# Why am I getting this error when accessing Facebook information of user?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Why is it giving me the error `2015-09-14 20:56:31.773 Musec[7207:3288153] FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter` I am trying to access user information like friends, email, etc. How do I fix the error? Below is the login plus the permissions to get access to user info.

```
@IBAction func loginWithFB(sender: AnyObject) {

    var permissions = [ "public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions,  block: {  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {

            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("success", sender: self)
                //let params = ["fields": "name, email, friends"]
                let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "name, email, friends"])
                graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    // Process error
                    println("Error: \(error)")
                }
                else
                {
                    //get username
                    let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                    println(userName)
                    //get Facebook ID
                    let email: NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                    println(email)
                    //get facebook friends who use app
                    let friendlist: NSString = result.valueForKey("friends") as! NSString
                    println(friendlist)

                }
                })

            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("success", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that `FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter` is actually an error. It is just a Log. If you will run the code and set a break point you will find that, error is actually `nil` and you will be able to successfully compile the code and see the `else` portion of the code getting executed.

Now, you are trying to access the `name` of Facebook user but not passing `name` in the `fields`. That is why you will get `name` as `null`. Pass `name` as list of parameters.

```
let params = ["fields": "name, email, friends"] <----- This line
```

Or here:

```
let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "name, email, friends"])
```

Now, you will be able to fetch `name, email and friends` of the Facebook user.

Comment: I'm still getting the `FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter`

Comment: Ignore that part. It is just a log set by facebook SDK. It is not an error or warning. You are good to go

Comment: How come the name, email, friends are not being printed?

Comment: Yes I added the name.

Comment: I am getting this when I am breakpointing. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzusujy8zr5kvdy/Screenshot%202015-09-14%2023.58.44.png?dl=0. Where should the condition be?

Comment: Can you please mention in your question where you are doing the login code?

Comment: Does it print "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!", when you do signup? or does it print "User logged in through Facebook!" when you login?

Comment: If I sign up it says "User signed up and logged in through Facebook", and everytime I click the login with facebook button after I signed up I get the "User logged in through facebook".